# Access a property of an object inside a method of that class

Tags: php

I'm trying to access a property of an object inside a method of that class.  Here's what I have so far:

```
class Readout{
    private $digits = array();
    public function Readout($value) {
        $length = strlen($value);
        for ($n = 0; $n < $length; $n++) {
            $digits[] = (int) $value[$n];
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to say `$x = new Readout('12345')`, where this creates a new `Readout` object with its `$digits` property set to the array `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

I seem to recall there's some issue with scope in PHP, where `$digits` might not be visible inside `Readout`, so I tried replacing `$digits[] =` with `$this->$digits[] =`, but that gave me a syntax error.

Comment: What version of PHP are you working with? Because with PHP5+ you should really specify the constructor as `__construct($value)` and not the name of the class. Also from the manual: *"As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the good syntax is:

```
$this->digits[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax to access a class property inside a class method in your case is:

```
$this->digits[];
```

To create a new Readout object with 12345 set, you have to implement the class like this:

```
class Readout {
    private $digits = array();

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $length = strlen($value);
        for ($n = 0; $n < $length; $n++) {
            $this->digits[] = (int) $value[$n];
        }
    }
}

$x = new Readout('12345');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the correct way to call variables in a class varies based on whether you're accessing them as static or instanced (non-static) variables.

```
class Readout{
    private $digits = array();
    ...
}

$this->digits; //read/write this attribute from within the class

class Readout{
    private static $digits = array();
    ...
}

self::$digits; //read/write this attribute from within the class
```

Comment: In short, the correct way to set a new index on it would be: $this->digits[] = 'value'; in the context you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

**This works as well**

```
<?php
class Readout{
    public $digits = array();
    public function Readout($value) {

        $this->digits = implode(',',str_split($value));


     }
}

$obj = new Readout(12345);

echo '['.$obj->digits.']';

?>
```